# Jsoup encoding in post requests

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am having this issue when posting a POST request to the Cyrillic. I Have been using JSoup and tried something similar to this and the site uses win1251 encoding

. header ("Content-Type", "application / x-www-form-urlencoded; charset = UTF-8")

but it is not working? what could be the issue

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Problem solved. I have edited the source code of jsoup to make it work.

Comment: Can you clarify in more detail what you did?

Comment: explain this plx

Answer (score 0):

I've have found a solution for this without changing jsoup code (including XMLHttpRequest call):

**NOTE**: site is my own bean with info about sites I'm wrapping

```
String postParams[]=null;
if (site.isPostRequest()) {
    String urlParams[]=url.split("\\?");
    url=urlParams[0];
    postParams=urlParams[1].split("[=|&]");
}
Integer timeout=site.getTimeout();
if (timeout==null)
    timeout=2*1000;
if (StringUtil.isEmpty(site.getEncoding()))
    site.setEncoding(UTF_8);
URL _url=new URL(url);
URLConnection con=_url.openConnection();
con.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
if (site.isPostRequest()) {
    Connection con2=Jsoup.connect(url);
    if (site.isXMLHttpRequest()) {
        con2.header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        con2.referrer(site.getProtocol()+site.getDomain());
    }
    con2.header("Accept-Charset", site.getEncoding());
    con2.data(postParams);
    doc=con2.post();
    doc.outputSettings(doc.outputSettings().charset(site.getEncoding()));
} else {
    if (site.isXMLHttpRequest()) {
        con.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        con.setRequestProperty("referrer",site.getProtocol()+site.getDomain());
    }
    doc=Jsoup.parse(con.getInputStream() , site.getEncoding(), url);
}
```